# Writing image file to Azure blob container using Spark

Tags: azure, pyspark, azure-blob-storage, databricks

I have two two Azure container `src` and `dst`. `src` contains image files and it is mounted inside `/dbfs/mnt/` on databrics. I have a seperate dataframe where we have `src` and `dst` path mapping.

What I am trying to do is to copy data from mounted `src` container to `dest` container using spark.
I can read data from src easily as it is mounted however how to copy data using in pure spark way.
I know I can use dbutils

```
dbutils.fs.cp(src_path, dest_path)
```

but I am not sure how fast it is. Also we can not use dbutils tools in spark function.

I have service principal configured with all the needed access.

Answer (score 1):

In order to read images (or blobs), for this use case, you can explore these ways:

`CASE 1: You need to manipulate the content of the image before copy`

1. Read data binary content using pyspark in a dataframe ([docs](https://docs.databricks.com/en/external-data/binary.html))
2. Write a UDF or Pandas UDF that is applied on each row of the dataframe (basically an I/O function `lambda x:process_image(x)`)

`CASE 2: You just need to move files from one container to another`

1. Write a UDF/ Pandas UDF function that uses azure storage client library to manipulate files in a storage account. An example function would be `lambda src_path, target_path: cp_file(src_path, target_path)`